# Asking for a promised promotion

Tags: promotion

When I was hired, my manager and HR felt that I had potential for band X+1 but put me in X with an assurance that I will be promoted to X+1 if I was able to demonstrate that I could handle technically complex projects.

Now, I think I have managed such projects and I have a feeling that my boss also feels the same way. Should I raise this topic immediately with my boss or wait for an appraisal discussion?

Comment: Sound them out.  Figure out whether they think the same way.  It's possible they aren't perceiving it the way you are, and it's also possible they promised you more than they're willing to deliver on.  The +1 might have simply been motivation.

Comment: How long has passed since you were hired?  How "hard" is your data to show you have effectively managed these projects?  Do you have under budget / under deadline data?  Do you have numerous examples of overcoming unforeseen complications?  You need to be prepared to defend your assertions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I raise this topic immediately with my boss or wait for an
>   appraisal discussion?

Unless it was specifically indicated that this could only happen during a formal appraisal session, simply find a convenient time to discuss this with your boss.

I meet with each of my team members individually every week. If you were working for me, it would be perfectly appropriate to use that week meeting as an opportunity to remind me of my promise.

Comment: I has a 1x1 with my boss ( not about this topic) and he indicated to me that I was doing very well and that after I show results on another project that would be a way for me to go up. I think he's indicating to me indirectly that he needs more data points. I think I'll wait.

Comment: @Wabbit I think it would make sense to formalise the conditions under which you get the promotion. This could be that at your next performance meeting you get the promotion given a set of conditions.